In compound nouns is there a way to distinguish which is the subject or the object?
I am translating a video game into German and have the phrase "troll kidnapper," meaning a troll who kidnapped a child. I would like to use a compound word like "Trollentführer," but I am afraid this would imply that he was a kidnapper (subject) of trolls (object), not a troll who kidnaps. This seems to be the pattern with existing words, e.g. kidnapper is Kinderdieb or Kindsentführer - thief of children - and dognapper is Hundeentführer.
Does the word order make a difference? Would I need to say something like "Entführertroll" to make the meaning clear?

Just wondering, is "troll kidnapper" inherently clear in English, or is it at least ambiguous as to whether the troll is the victim or the perpetrator?

@O.R.Mapper It's not inherently clear and unambiguous. My initial reading of troll kidnapper was as someone who kidnaps trolls (perhaps working for three billy goats).

Not your question, but btw in any decent fantasy story, someone who kidnaps trolls would be called a "trollnapper".

I think the English word order ("troll kidnapper") is plainly incorrect. See "window cleaner", "fortune-teller", "bread maker", "child molester". Adjective order exceptions exist in set phrases like "attorney general", "code red", "court-martial", but I couldn't find any examples of noun verb-er where the noun is doing the action.

Yes, the order in compounds matters. This is similar to how the order of words matters in English.
The thing described in detail by the compound is the last part of a compound.
Thus a troll kidnapper (someone who kidnaps trolls) is a Troll-Entführer and a kidnapper troll (a troll who kidnaps others) is a Entführer-Troll.
Similar:

a Dosenbier is a beer in a can while a Bierdose the the beer can (a can used to hold beer).
a Stangenbohne is a bean which grows on a stick while the Bohnenstange is the stick on which the bean grows
a Polstersitz is a cushioned seating while the Sitzpolster is the cushion itself used for seating.
a Tischsäge is a saw used on or mounted on a table (table saw) while a Sägetisch is the table on which is sawn.

Last: Now, why did I write the example with Troll with a hyphen but not the others? Because to me it made the unusual compound easier to read. This is not a necessity and left for the writer to decide, but can be a good idea for longer and / or unusual compounds.

In a compound noun the last part names what the thing is. The part before that is a further description of that last part.
Decide whether your character is a person that kidnaps children all the time and who sometimes is also a troll, or if it's always a troll who sometimes kidnaps children. I think the later is true, so the main word is Troll and Kidnaper is a further description of that Troll. So it's an ...

Entführertroll.


Trollentführer
This is relatively clearly a person who kidnaps trolls, because kidnapping is an action and it is more likely that an action that is combined with a person means that the action is performed on that person. Here are other examples:

Frauenversteher
A Versteher is person who understands other people. A Frauenversteher could be interpreted as a woman who understands other people, but in fact it is a person (in this special context a man) who is able to understand women.

Kundenbetreuer
A Betreuer is person who cares about other people and who manages them. This word could mean a customer who manages something or someone, but in fact it is a person who cares about customers (an account manager)


